# how to transpose CSV file with php

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

just wondering how I display the data in a CSV file diffrently, the code a have now
[displays the data
like this inexcel/google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujhtT.png)

but I want to display the data in excel/google docs [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxnJG.png)

This is the code I am using is there anyway to modify it to give me the result i want?

```
$data2 = [
  ["number of drinks:" => "1"],
  ["number of snacks:" => "2 "],
  ["number of cats" => "3"],
  ["numbers of dogs:" => "4"],

$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

$headers = [];
$values = [];

foreach ( $data2 as $form_section ) {
    foreach ( $form_section as $heading => $value ) {
        array_push( $headers, $heading );
        array_push( $values, $value );
    }
}

fputcsv( $fh, $headers,);
fputcsv( $fh, $values,);
fclose($fh);
];
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete, what is the $form_section variable?

Comment: @SyedHussim form_section is just parsing data2 values, then the second foreach grabs each element as $key => $value pairs

Comment: its just the key for the array $data2 "number of drinks:" ""number of snacks:" ect

Comment: Gosh, my bad, it's been a while since I did PHP.

Comment: That array is not closed until the end of the script!!! Thats not going to compile

Comment: I wonder how you managed to obtain that code and run it but you're not able to do the much less complicated variant. Are you looking for copy&paste assistance? If so, provide reference from where you've obtained the code.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the array in the format needed to pass it to fputcsv.

```
$data2 = [
  ["number of drinks:" => "1"],
  ["number of snacks:" => "2 "],
  ["number of cats" => "3"],
  ["numbers of dogs:" => "4"],
];

$tmp = [];

$fh = fopen("file.csv", "w");


foreach($data2 as $row){ 
        $header = key($row);
        $value = $row[$header];
        
        fputcsv( $fh, [$header, $value]);
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Please make sure that you explain your answer in order to describe the issues presented and how you resolved it, this helps the OP and future readers learn the issue and how to avoid it rather than "here's teh codez"